How to configure x11VNC.service on Rocky Linux 9.3
So my team is building a few Autodesk Flame systems using Rocky Linux 9.3 that we would like to be able to access using VNC.
We installed x11VNC but are only able to access it remotely if we start and enable the vnc app after it has turned on using a local monitor and keyboard, defeating the purpose.
How do we configure the x11vnc.service in order to be able to access it with VNC without having to first go and start the app manually and locally? Would also like to be able to 'log off' the Rocky Linux 9.3 system and still see its login screen in order to switch users while connected through VNC remotely.
Here is my x11vnc.service file:
[Unit] Description=VNC server for the current X11 session After=display-manager.service
[Service] ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -cursor arrow -display :0 -forever -loop -noallinput -nobell -nodpms -noipv6 -nomodtweak -nopw -norc -nossl -noxdamage -noxfixes -noxkb -noxrecord -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -reopen -repeat -rfbauth /root/.vnc/x11vnc.passwd -rfbport 5900 -rfbversion 3.8 -shared Restart=on-failure RestartSec=3
[Install] WantedBy=graphical.target
Thank you soo much for anybody who can help me solve this issue. Ill be forever in your debt.
